# .htaccess: Redirect without changing url

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I would like to have a URL be redirected to a different page on the same domain but without the browser changing the URL. So the page `www.mydomain.co.uk/tour/` should point towards `www.mydomain.co.uk/` but without changing.

I have looked at a lot of similar questions on Stackoverflow but all the solutions seem to change the URL for me.

**CODE:**

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/tour
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.co.uk/ [L]
```

Comment: Try removing the domain.  Also try using `[P]`

Comment: Awesome adding the [P] to the answer below did it

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Because you provide a full URL in your rewrite rule it is automatically treated as a redirection. Replace the full URL with just a slash and it should work, i.e.:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/tour
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [P]
```

You can even shorten it down to:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?tour.* / [P]
```

Comment: You should inform of the risks of having mod_proxy enabled like Apache does here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: Thank you! This is what stuck me too. Makes sense.

Comment: it works when I try to rewrite `/fake-url` to a real file like `/new.php`, but when I try to rewrite `/fake-url` to `/another-fake` while real is `index.php` it changes the url.

Answer (score 3):

1- Use [P] instead of [L]

2- Use $s at the end of second line to have a set of urls redirects and remove / at the end of it too.

The code will look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/tour
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [P]
```

which treats with more than the index page of the folder tour.

Comment: This is exactly the same as [Michal M's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895980/htaccess-redirect-without-changing-url/14896042#14896042)...

Comment: Please recheck, the $1 sign is there!

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I didn't notice the change. To ensure no one else makes the same mistake, I recommend editing your answer to mention Michal's existing answer, and why yours is different

Answer (score -6):

Try just to change [L] to [P] and I assume it will work.

Comment: Isn't that what the already accepted answer tot he question just said to do?