# .htaccess - Show contents of original URL under a different URL

Tags: .htaccess

I would like the contents of my original url  `http://example.com/` display under this URL: `http://example.com/seller/nokia` when accessed. The `nokia` is dynamic. How can I achieve this?

The url must be persistent across all pages, for example if I navigate to the page `http://example.com/seller/nokia/about.php` then it would be mapped to `http://example.com/about.php`

I am not using any framework.

I am a newbie in htaccess so I am really hoping someone can help me. I am pretty sure this is not a duplicate of any existing questions in StackOverflow.

Comment: are you working with any framework ?

Comment: @jok3r no I am not working with any framework.

Comment: i think you need to Rewrite some rules in .htaccess . try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895980/htaccess-redirect-without-changing-url

Comment: try it and lemme know :)

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't work for me. I've tested using XAMPP

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .htaccess to redirect all php and html pages to be sourced from the home directory.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/seller/(?:.*)/(.*\.(?:html|php))$ /$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

This will redirect `/seller/nokia/about.php` to `/about.php`.

Alternatively, you can still show `/seller/nokia/about.php` as the url and source it from `/about.php`. To do so, just change the `R` flag to a `QSA` flag.