# Woocommerce product categories with same names

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, slug, custom-taxonomy

On my wordpress website, i sell second hand and new material for sound.
I use woocommerce to show my product with catalog mode.

I want to display my product with 2 big category, but the children of this category was the same. For example:

```
- New (mywebsite.com/new)
-- Line (mywebsite.com/new/line)
-- Hybrid (mywebsite.com/new/hybrid)
```

And display my second hand like

```
- Second hand(mywebsite.com/second-hand)
-- Line (mywebsite.com/second-hand/line)
-- Hybrid (mywebsite.com/second-hand/hybrid)
```

So i create 2 category "Line". 1 in Used, 1 in second hand. But when i change the slug of the second category, i have this error

**The slug “line” is already in use by another term.**

How to solve this problem and have great link ?

Comment: Ideally you set the slug of **Line** with parent **New** as **new-line** and the slug of **Line** with parent **Second** as **second-line** . Currently wordpress does not allow you to have children categories with same slugs.  You can still set up some rules in htaccess to have pretty urls while having different slugs.

Comment: To redirect urls with htaccess but without changing the url in browser have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895980/htaccess-redirect-without-changing-url

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You dont know plugin ? i have a lot of category..

Comment: No Sorry. Another option would be to have Second Hand and New as Tags instead of parent categories. In order to have one set of Line, Hybrid etc..

Comment: You are confusing `name` and `slug`… In Wordpress, **each term of a taxonomy or custom taxonomy has always a different slug**…and "Product category" is a custom taxonomy maid by Woocommerce. So when coding **is better to target the `slug` or `term_id`** instead of `name`… The `name` is mostly used for display.

Answer (score 0):

Currently wordpress does not allow child categories/terms to have same name even tough they have a different parent.

What I would suggest is to have the slugs as follows:

For New Items:

```
- New (mywebsite.com/new)
-- Line (mywebsite.com/new/line)
-- Hybrid (mywebsite.com/new/hybrid)
```

For Second Hand:

```
- Second hand(mywebsite.com/second-hand)
-- Line (mywebsite.com/second-hand/second-hand-line)
-- Hybrid (mywebsite.com/second-hand/second-hand-hybrid)
```

Than in your htacces you would implement the following rules for each child category in second hand:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/second-hand/line
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /second-hand/second-hand-line [P]
```

I think the only issue you will be having is when it comes to SEO since your sitemap will still be populated with the urls as set according to the slug.

**Also please note that using the [P] flag in the htaccess triggers the apache module `mod_proxy`**

**Another Option**

You can set **New** and **Second Hand** as tags instead of parent categories and therefore you will have only one set of your current child categories. Then you can add a tag filter in order to show only new or second hand for that particular category.

And you will end up with the following links:

```
- New (mywebsite.com/new)
- Second Hand (mywebsite.com/second-hand)
- Line (mywebsite.com/line)
- Hybrid (mywebsite.com/hybrid)
```