# Own Image Hosting Page: How to always open an html file but with image given in the url?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, .htaccess

I'm currently working on my own image hosting site: https://img.baeni.de

Everything is working properly but I want to change something.

Currently, when opening a link from a shared image, it just simply opens the image. I want to open another html site with an image instead. The image should be the image which is given in the url.

Example:
Visiting img.baeni.de/u/123.png opens the construct.html file & sets [image] so that the image, which is given in the url, will be shown on that page.

Important: The URL should still be img.baeni.de/u/123.png & NOT img.baeni.de/construct.html

I DON'T want to get spoonfeeded but want to receive some ideas of how you guys would handle something like that.

Best regards,
baeni

Comment: .htaccess redirect or mod_rewrite would probably do it if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: Just a thought -- definitely not a complete answer.

Comment: I thought about that aswell. Seems to be a good solution for the url!

The question about how I could get the image (in example 123.png) into the html file. I mean I want to use just one html file for all links so I cannot just refer the image path directly in html file as I would need to create one file per image & that would explode the server.

Comment: That's what .htaccess can do. It can take the variable out of the URL and serve a "different" page. The URL doesn't change, and you'd only need 1 file on the server. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895980/htaccess-redirect-without-changing-url

Comment: I'm not good at .htaccess at all -- so I'm no help for this question. But that's the route you should probably go. Essentially, the .htaccess file will read the URL and rewrite it "behind the scenes". So a visitor going to any img.baeni.de/u/### would be served construct.php?id=### .  The visitor will only ever see the first URL they typed in and not the construct page URL. That happens "behind the scenes"

Comment: I changed the tags in your question to .htaccess and regex. But if you do it, it'll happen sooner, and you'll probably get a better answer!

Comment: Also, be aware that serving a .html page "behind the scenes" won't allow you to grab the information from the URL... but using a PHP page will. But you originally tagged this question with PHP so I think you'll be able to use a .htaccess rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, but this may work for you.

Put the following in a .htaccess in the u/ folder (or maybe the root folder).

`RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^u/(.*)$ construct.html?img=$1 [QSA]`

When the visitor arrives at **img.baeni.de/u/123.png** the web server will actually serve the page **img.baeni.de/construct.html?img=123.png**.

You can use javascript like this to get the URL:

```
// Will get /u/123.png
  var urlstr = window.location.pathname;

// Will turn it into 123.png
  var imgstr = str.split("/").pop();
```

To load the image src after the page load, create a container (like a `div`) to hold the image. Then window.onload can populate this container with the image, or the error image.

```
<div id="image"></div>

<script>
  // On page load call an immediately invoked function to load the image
  window.onload(

    function(){

      // Will get /u/123.png
      var urlstr = window.location.pathname;

      // Will turn it into 123.png
      var imgstr = "/gfx/" + str.split("/").pop();

      // Error Image
      var errorImg = '/gfx/error.png';

      // Create the image in the div container
      document.getElementById('image').innerHTML="<img src='" + imgstr + "' onerror='this.onerror=null;this.src=\"" + errorImg + "\"'>";

    }()
  );
</script>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208382/discussion-on-answer-by-jeff-vdovjak-own-image-hosting-page-how-to-always-open).