# .htaccess rule to map all urls starting with localhost/eu to localhost

Tags: .htaccess

I have my website running on localhost... I want that, if some user type on browser localhost/eu then localhost/eu internally map to localhost.
User type any url localhost/eu then localhost/eu map to localhost.. Rest of the url should not change..

```
For example...
localhost/eu map to localhost
localhost/eu/category map to localhost/category
localhost/eu/products map to localhost/products
localhost/eu/brands map to localhost/brands
localhost/eu/items map to localhost/items
```

Here is my .htaccess rule which works for first url localhost/eu map to localhost but not works for rest of the urls..

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/eu
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [P]
```

Comment: Why are you using `[P]` (proxy) here?

Comment: I looked this from here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895980/htaccess-redirect-without-changing-url

and this is working for localhost and localhost/eu..... but not working for other urls..

Comment: Try: `RewriteRule ^eu(/.*)?$ $1 [L]`

Comment: RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/eu
RewriteRule ^eu(/.*)?$ $1 [P]
Rule worked for me... with 2 problems is i need to write localhost/eu/ instead of localhost/eu
Second Problem is some times i get 
Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request

Reason: Error reading from remote server
After refreshing 4-5 times i get response...

Comment: You asked _exactly_ the same question yesterday. The attempt to help with that failed, since you refused to answer questions. Please read about how this page works and why you are expected _not_ to ask the same question twice. Thanks. Voting to close this question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP asked the same question before.