# Ignore undefined url characters htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url

I have google conversions (most likely analytics tracker) like site.com/postname&sa=U&ved=2ahdff1kkkmoECAgQAg&usg=AOvVaw0ayMEVIHqWpMNVGcZRwNcA

I get 404 error, because it is not query string (no ? in url).

I try using htacceess to ignore &sa=U&ved=2ahdff1kkkkmoECAgQAg&usg=AOvVaw0ayMEVIHqWpMNVGcZRwNcA with a bunch of instructions, but none work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^&sa=U&ved=(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^&sa=U&ved=(.*)$ /$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^&sa\=U&ved\=(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^&sa=U&ved=(.*)
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$0 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

**UPD:**
I was able to make a rule that the characters are processed. But it creates a 301 redirect. I need the url remains the same, and the result pages without garbage (site.com/postname), ignored only unnecessary characters in the url (such as &sa=U&ved=2ahdff1kkkmoECAgQAg&usg=AOvVaw0ayMEVIHqWpMNVGcZRwNcA).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule (.*)&sa\=U&ved\=(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1? [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

There was a similar topic, but his solution to the flag [P] gives a 500 error - [.htaccess: Redirect without changing url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895980/htaccess-redirect-without-changing-url)

Comment: "But it creates a 301 redirect." - But if you don't create a 301 redirect then you potentially have a _duplicate content_ problem. Presumably `/postname` is the canonical URL, and the URL you are otherwise linking to, so you need to "fix" the URL with a 301 redirect. "most likely analytics tracker" - But how/where exactly are these URLs being generated. Are these URL parameters not needed for your analytics?

Comment: @MrWhite 
1. I think the plugins will work off the canonical tag.
2. I only see hits on such addresses and errors 404. Although if you go to google and look at the urls of any output result can be seen:  
~~~<a href="https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html" data-ved="2ahUKEwjKwPC60ub9AhXCs4sKHR1wC_kQFnoECAoQAQ" ping="/url?sa=t&amp;source=web&amp;rct=j&amp;url=https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html&amp;ved=2ahUKEwjKwPC60ub9AhXCs4sKHR1wC_kQFnoECAoQAQ">~~~

Comment: "Are these URL parameters not needed for your analytics?"  Before that I had only 404 errors with such urls. Googling, I realized that it is analytics generates such urls with trackers and hits. I decided that this must be fixed somehow.